# Options for in-cloud deep learning iOS

Tags: ios, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

Is there any in-cloud deep-learning solutions that makes data predictions?

For example, user may write some text into text field and algorithm (deep learning code)
should suggest one of 8 categories based on input. 
If it suggests wrong variant - user may select correct one, and algorithm should improve itself
in real-time without new app’s release. Also learning model should be shared between users.

Or another example:
User writes some text into field, and algorithm improves that text based on trained input.

Is there are any solutions for that available right now on iOS?
Which is the best for price/value?

Update: CoreML is not an option because it doesn't share model and requires app release to update the model.

Comment: Check this: http://alexsosn.github.io/ml/2015/11/05/iOS-ML.html#web

Comment: @AlexanderSosnovshchenko great thank you! do you have experience with some of them?

Comment: not much, I prefer on-device learning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you are looking for can be covered by [Core ML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml), starting in iOS 11.

Here you have 2 links to the WWDC talks:

- [Introducing Core ML](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/703/)
- [Core ML in depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/710/)

The first step is for you to [build a Core ML model](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/getting_a_core_ml_model).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! I’ve explored Core ML - looks like it has bunch of limitations and in this case it can’t help: 1. The model is stored on device and can be more than 500 mb (based on model examples from Apple site) does it mean that app will grow from 20 mb to 520 mb if I have really smart model? 2. It’s not shared between users so if user 1 teach the model, user 2 will not get that result and is going to use old model. 3 to update model I must release new version of app.